# print lines matching criteria from two files with different formats

Tags: awk

I am trying to print those lines in `file1` that match `file2`. `$1` in `file1` has the value that in stored in array c, then looked up in `file2` `$1`:`$2`. That is the first criteria used to match the lines but not the only one. `$5` of `file1` must match `$4` of `file2`, if those two criteria are met and `$2` in `file1` is `SNV or INDEL` and `$3`
in `file1` is `exonic` then the matching line from `file1` is printed. If the lines do not match then they are skipped. The below `awk` executes but no output results and in this example, there should be one line. My actual data is several thousand lines all in the below format. Thank you :).

**file 1**

```
##reference=hg19
##referenceURI=hg19
# locus type    location    function    coding

chr1:11184539   CNV
chr1:11184573   REF exonic
chr1:11189845   REF exonic
chr2:47630550   SNV intronic
chr4:55141050   SNV exonic  synonymous  c.1701A>G
chr4:55141050   INDEL   exonic  nonsynonymous    c.1697_1711delGCCCAGATGGACATG
```

**file2**

```
chr4    55141050    COSM742     c.1696_1713delAGCCCAGATGGACATGAAinsCGC  p.Ser566_Glu571delinsArg
chr4    55141050    COSM12417   c.1697_1711delGCCCAGATGGACATG   p.Ser566_Glu571delinsLy
```

**awk**

```
awk 'FNR==3 {next}
  # skip first three lines in file1   
             {FS = OFS = "\t"}
  # define input and output as tab-delimited         
               NR==FNR{c[$1]; next} ($1":"$2) in c && NR==FNR{c[$5];next}$4 in c && $2 ~ /SNV|INDEL/ && $3=="exonic"' file1 file2
 # process each line in file matching on criteria
```

**desired output**

```
chr4:55141050   INDEL   exonic  synonymous  c.1697_1711delGCCCAGATGGACATG
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ a[$1":"$2]=substr($4,1,6); next }
     NF>=5 && $2~/SNV|INDEL/ && $3=="exonic" &&
     ($1 in a) && a[$1]==substr($5,1,6)' file2 OFS='\t' file1
```

The output:

```
chr4:55141050   INDEL   exonic  nonsynonymous    c.1697_1711delGCCCAGATGGACATG
```